# Query works but takes a lot of time to execute

Tags: mysql

I have a query which is meant to get the beatmaps of followed users only.

```
SELECT   *,
         maps.uid,
         maps.add_time,
         maps.id as mapid
FROM     maps
  LEFT JOIN follows ON
         (follows.fid = maps.uid
          AND follows.uid = 3443963) 
WHERE follows.id IS NOT NULL
AND maps.uid != 3443963
AND add_time = (SELECT max(add_time)
                FROM maps i
                WHERE i.sid = maps.sid)
GROUP BY sid
ORDER BY maps.add_time DESC LIMIT 9
```

Query works but takes over 6 seconds to execute. Is there any way to make it run faster?

Comment: Can you show the table structure?

Comment: maps has id, uid, add_time. follows has uid, fid (the user who was followed)

Comment: How many rows do you have ?

Comment: Have you created indexes?

Comment: Around 3k rows, but when I just SELECT the entire table it goes fine and fast. Guess the JOIN causes it. and yes i have indexes

Comment: What do you get when you execute the Query with EXPLAIN before the Query. You have to have indexes on maps.uid, follows.fid, maps.sid and maps.add_time

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nmgjk7
This is what I get. Every user can upload beatmaps and I want the user to see only his following users' maps only.

Comment: If I put EXPLAIN in front of my Query I get a response with id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered. Can you try to get this output? I need to see if you have all the Indexes set in the correct way.

Comment: Ohh, sorry I didn't know that. http://prntscr.com/nmgt04

Comment: Thanks, I don't see any indexes in the result column `possible_keys`. If you add the keys `maps.uid`, `follows.fid`, `maps.sid` and `maps.add_time` your Query will become super fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add **indexes** for the columns you use in your Select Query.

**Example Query:**

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename`
ADD INDEX (`uid`);
```

**You need the following indexes:**

`maps.uid`, `follows.fid`, `maps.sid` and `maps.add_time`

**Queries:**

```
ALTER TABLE `maps`
ADD INDEX (`uid`);

ALTER TABLE `maps`
ADD INDEX (`add_time`);

ALTER TABLE `maps`
ADD INDEX (`sid`);

ALTER TABLE `follows`
ADD INDEX (`fid`);
```